# Python DLNA get directory/file list

Tags: python, image

I've got a Lumix, and I take pic with a command over http.

But my problem I can't have access to pics. My camera show on Windows Media Player and I can access to the pics but I want to list them and add my photos/download on my python script.

Thank for reply

I've tried to connect over upnpc but doesn't show my camera.